# cv2.imread path integrity warning

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to open a jpg file on Jupyter Notebook using this code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/Users/redacted/Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg')
```

When I run it, I get the following warning:

> [ WARN:0@2119.814] global /private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_506zufg7xt/croots/recipe/opencv-suite_1664548331847/work/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('/Users/redacted/Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

I've tried several things to get around it:

1. Changing the file type from jpg to bmp and png
2. Moving the file into/out of folders
3. Using \ instead of /
4. I'm running this through anaconda, so I've updated anaconda
5. Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda's opencv package
6. Using the following code in place of the above

```
path = r'C:Users/redacted/Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Everything I've read indicates that something is wrong with the path. But I've checked my spelling and directory order dozens of times at this point. Regardless, I get the same warning. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Is it just a simple syntax error that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You don't specify what type of system or tell us the full path of your file? I get different impressions from the little you included. Your first code block makes it look like you are on Unix-style machine. The last one with `path = r'C:Users/redacted/Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg'` makes it seems like you are on a Windows machine. What is the full path to the file itself? Where is your notebook in the file hierarchy relative this? What do you see when you run `pwd` in the notebook?

Comment: Good points. I'm very new to this, so sorry for the omissions. (1) I'm on MacOS. (2) As far as I know, what I've given is the full path to the file. (3) When I run `pwd` in the notebook, it returns `'/Users/redacted'`.

Comment: So definitely `r'C:Users/redacted/Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg'` isn't going to help you. That is something closer to windows-style path (but still a little off). Since your working directory is already `/Users/redacted`, did you try `img = cv2.imread('Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg')
`? (Also try a varation on that with the `/` in front of Dekstop.) Those options would be a relative path. Had problems reading files here before? Do you know enough Python to easily test saving a new file from inside your notebook and reopening it? 100% sure the `.jpg` is valid? Opens elsewhere?

Comment: (1) Tried `img = cv2.imread('Desktop/1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg')`, with and without the /Desktop variation. It still returned the warning for both. (2) This is the first time I've tried reading a file with opencv, but I've read excel and csv files with pandas before with no problems. (3) Unfortunately, no. I can figure it out, but I won't be able to do it easily/quickly. (4) I'm not sure what you mean by "is the jpg. valid".

Comment: Also the `/private/var/folders/s`-stuff makes me concerned you installed part of the openCV stuff in somewhere that cannot access your file. That would be consistent with you usually being able to open csv and other files fine.

Comment: Well, I installed openCV through the terminal. `conda install opencv`. I did have some trouble getting it to install the first time. It had some kind of conflict with the Spyder package that came with anaconda, so I had to uninstall Spyder before I could install opencv. Does that shed any light on what happening, by chance?

Comment: Add a line at the start of your program that does `print(os.getcwd())` then you will know where your current directory is. Copy your finger image to that directory and then open it with `im = cv2.imread('1__M_Left_index_finger.jpg')` if that works we know your image is fine and your path is wrong. If it doesn't work, either your installation is messed up or your image is corrupt - you can then check your image with `exiftool YOURIMAGE`

Comment: Install sounds right then. That's reassuring. Maybe it installs that codec to a special place. The path just didn't seem like a typical place, but I don't deal a lot with inner workings associated with CV2. Hopefully some of Mark's suggestion shed some light. Alternative, sort of converse to Mark's suggestion, is to find an image file someone else uses cv2.imread to read and then try putting it with you notebook, or in the working directory, and opening it.

Comment: An alternative way to check your file's integrity would be to open a session served by MyBinder via one of the options listed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/opencv-and-mybinder/8583/2)  and try `cv2.imread()`.  Usually there were be a `launch binder` badge an it will bring up a session where openCV2 should already be installed and working. I cannot guarantee all those are still working but I suspect some of them might. It may give you something to at least compare what works and what may not.